# Is "0" valid HTML5 class name?

Tags: html

Is "0" valid HTML5 class name?

For example:

```
<div class="0"></div>
```

**Edit:**
just to clarify, im asking about HTML5, not CSS. As per https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html "When specified on HTML elements, the class attribute must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens" where separated tokens are https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens which looks like "0" is ok.

Comment: short answer NO. You can choose class name as `letter` combine with `number` or something similar or letters only.

Comment: No, you can follow some naming conventions refer [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-naming-conventions-that-will-save-you-hours-of-debugging-35cea737d849/)

Comment: Why not just run it through e.g. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea and find out?

Comment: good point, validator had no problem with that, thanks

Comment: Wait... isn't it better to use descriptive class name such as `image` or `title`? Wouldn't it make your code a bit nicer to maintain than `624472` and `816410`?

Comment: Much better - I just wanted to know if i have to prevent this edge case in some generated HTML where class is not used for CSS to avoid generating invalid HTML - I was not sure since in CSS this is not valid as was pointed out in one answer.

Answer (score 3):

## No

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, **classes**, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they **cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters), emphasis mine.

Comment: just to clarify, im asking about HTML5, not CSS. As per https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html "When specified on HTML elements, the class attribute must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens" where separated tokens are https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens which looks like "0" is ok.

Comment: @tdd That's correct, but you modify classes using CSS. And in CSS starting with digits is not allowed.